# Постановка кавычек у сорта роз

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

Нужно ли заключать в кавычки придуманный автором сорт роз?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Ответы справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2):

> Полный академический справочник «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» указывает, что названия видов и сортов сельскохозяйственных культур, овощей, **цветов** и т. п. – термины агрономии и садоводства – выделяются кавычками и  пишутся со строчной буквы: *клубника «виктория», виноград «шардоне», тюльпан «черный принц»*.
>
> В специальной литературе возможно написание с прописной буквы без кавычек: *сорт Карусель*.

Это же говорится и в справочнике Розенталя, в параграфе [**Названия пород животных, видов и сортов растений**](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=26):

> В неспециальных текстах названия сортов растений, овощей, фруктов заключаются в кавычки и пишутся со строчной буквы (в том числе и имена собственные): *клубника «виктория»; помидор «иосиф прекрасный»; яблоки «пепин литовский», «бельфлёр китайский», «шафран-китайка»*.
>
> В специальной литературе в названиях сортов растений, овощей, фруктов, **цветов** первое слово (и все имена собственные) пишется с прописной буквы: *крыжовник Слава Никольска, малина Мальборо, земляника Победитель, смородина Выставочная красная, яблоня Китайка золотая ранняя, слива Никольская белая, **роза Мария-Луиза**, фиалка Пармская, тюльпан Чёрный принц*.